# Variable used with a command PHP ,cannot get $line variable to use in code below...?

Tags: php

I am trying to use the `$line` variable inside the while loop below, to be used in the `$filter` variable, but it's not making it down into the command.

Why is this so?

```
<?php

// NEED TO GET THE $line variable OUT of the WHILE loop!!!!!

// Get the UID from the login by reading variables.txt...

       $fh = fopen('varibles.txt','r');
       $line = "";
       while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
       }
        fclose($fh); 

    $ldap_dn = "uid=testbind,ou=users,o=test,c=local";
    $ldap_password = "password";

    $ldap_con = ldap_connect("test.test.local");

    ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if(ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password)) {
        $filter = "(uid=$line)";
        $result = ldap_search($ldap_con,"o=test,c=local",$filter) or exit("Unable to search");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_con, $result);
        echo $entries[0]['cn'][0]."\n";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid user/pass or other errors!";
    }
         */ 
?>
```

Comment: You have `while ($line = fgets($fh)) { }` which just put the lines one by one inside the `$line`  variable and do nothing with them.

Answer (score 1):

A better  way will be this one:

```
  <?php

   $fh = fopen('varibles.txt','r');
   $line = "";
   while (!feof($fh)) {
      $line = $line = fgets($fh);
      echo $line."<br>";

   }
    fclose($fh); 

$ldap_dn = "uid=testbind,ou=users,o=test,c=local";
$ldap_password = "password";

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("test.test.local");

ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password)) {
    $filter = "(uid=$line)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_con,"o=test,c=local",$filter) or exit("Unable to search");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_con, $result);
    echo $entries[0]['cn'][0]."\n";
} else {
    echo "Invalid user/pass or other errors!";
}      
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 

  $filter = "(uid=$line)"; = This line still fails. I get this error.

Comment: $filter = "(uid=$line)"; = This line still fails. I get this error.
 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/bootstrap/www/ldap_cn_filter.php on line 34  

This is line 34:  echo $entries[0]['cn'][0]."\n";